# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to identify if radio option is selected or not - contains pseudo elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I am having hard time with identifying if radio option No is selected or not using Selenium Java. Below is the screenshot of the radio options on the web page. A workable solution is much appreciated.

[image]

Below is the HTML code. ::after (highlighted below) gets dynamically loaded when No option is selected.

[image]

I created below Java method that executes JavaScript that I am expecting to return whole label tag. It is currently printing out `null`. However, when I execute the script used below in Chrome browser console, it identifies the entire label tag including ::before and ::after pseudo elements.

```java
public String whichRadioOptionIsSelected() {
        String tag = "";
        List<WebElement> radioOptions = findElementsByXpath(".//div[@id='ButtonOptions']/label");

        for(int i = 1; i <= radioOptions.size(); i++) {
                String script = "return document.querySelector('div#ButtonOptions > label:nth-of-type("+i+") label', null);";
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                tag = (String) js.executeScript(script);
                System.out.println(tag);
            }        
        return tag;
    }
```

Comment: what happens when u use isSelected()  on input tag

Comment: Hello @PDHide, I created a separate method that used ```isSelected()``` and it always returned 'false'. Here is the code that I tried:

```java
public boolean whichRadioOptionSelected() {

        boolean isNoSelected = false;
        if (isElementPresent(conditionTrue)) {

            WebElement noOption = findElementByXpath(RADIO_NO);

            if (noOption.isSelected()) {
                isNoSelected = true;
            } else {
                isNoSelected = false;
            }
        }
        return isNoSelected;
    }
```

Comment: why to create separe method when u already have inbuilt method

Comment: What was the xpath in radio_no

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String whichRadioOptionIsSelected() {
        try {
            WebElement selectedOption = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='ButtonOptions']//input[@value='true']/following-sibling::label");
            if(selectedOption.isPresent())
                return selectedOption.getText();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }       
    }
```